# Replace all of a string based on its start

Tags: r, regex, string

I am trying to change elements of a string based on the first characters of the string. I need to do it that way instead of using the whole string, because I am scraping this data frequently and the latter part of the string changes often.

This is an example of the string I have:

```
teams <- structure(c(3L, 14L, 4L, 5L, 15L, 10L, 7L, 2L, 12L, 13L, 9L, 
        8L, 1L, 11L, 6L, 21L, 29L, 17L, 16L, 30L, 23L, 19L, 20L, 25L, 
        22L, 26L, 28L, 27L, 24L, 18L), .Label = c("Dallas MavericksÂ (13)Â", 
                                                  "Denver NuggetsÂ (8)Â", "Golden State WarriorsÂ (1)Â", "Houston RocketsÂ (3)Â", 
                                                  "Los Angeles ClippersÂ (4)Â", "Los Angeles LakersÂ (15)Â", "Memphis GrizzliesÂ (7)Â", 
                                                  "Minnesota TimberwolvesÂ (12)Â", "New Orleans PelicansÂ (11)Â", 
                                                  "Oklahoma City ThunderÂ (6)Â", "Phoenix SunsÂ (14)Â", "Portland Trail BlazersÂ (9)Â", 
                                                  "Sacramento KingsÂ (10)Â", "San Antonio SpursÂ (2)Â", "Utah JazzÂ (5)Â", 
                                                  "Atlanta HawksÂ (4)Â", "Boston CelticsÂ (3)Â", "Brooklyn NetsÂ (15)Â", 
                                                  "Charlotte HornetsÂ (7)Â", "Chicago BullsÂ (8)Â", "Cleveland CavaliersÂ (1)Â", 
                                                  "Detroit PistonsÂ (10)Â", "Indiana PacersÂ (6)Â", "Miami HeatÂ (14)Â", 
                                                  "Milwaukee BucksÂ (9)Â", "New York KnicksÂ (11)Â", "Orlando MagicÂ (13)Â", 
                                                  "Philadelphia 76ersÂ (12)Â", "Toronto RaptorsÂ (2)Â", "Washington WizardsÂ (5)Â"
        ), class = "factor")
```

I Want to change for example `"Golden State WarriorsÂ (1)Â"` for `GSW`, for that I have tried:

```
teams <- gsub("Golden", "GSW", teams)
```

which transforms that string into `"GSW State WarriorsÂ (1)Â"`capturing only first parts of the string element rather than the whole sting, I have also tried with `sub`, and every function I find when I call for `?gsub` (e.g. `grep`, `grepl`), but apparently I don't understand regular expressions all that well.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I’m a big fan of using regex but why not just use `substr(teams, 1, 3)` here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting and removing the first character of a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7723549/getting-and-removing-the-first-character-of-a-string)

Comment: @Sotos, I actually don't want to remove the first part, I want to use it to replace the whole string

Comment: ooopps... I actually meant to dupe it [with this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21675379/r-only-keep-the-3-x-first-characters-in-a-all-rows-in-a-column). Sorry

Comment: @Sotos, thanks, I probably choose the wrong example, I needed for example to change `"Golden State WarriorsÂ (1)Â"` to `GSW`, because of prior formating of other functions, I will re-edit the question

Comment: ahhh ok then...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `sub` and capture the first 3 characters as a group (`.^(.{3})`) followed by other characters (`.*`) and replace it with the backreference of that captured group

```
sub("^(.{3}).*", "\\1", teams)
```

#### Update

Based on the new info, we use regex lookarounds to match one or more non-capital letters (`[^A-Z]+`) that follows a capital letter after a word boundary (`(?<=\\b[A-Z])`) and replace it with blanks (`""`)

```
gsub("(?<=\\b[A-Z])[^A-Z]+", "", teams, perl = TRUE)
#[1] "GSW" "SAS" "HR"  "LAC" "UJ"  "OCT" "MG"  "DN"  "PTB" "SK"  "NOP" 
#[12] "MT"  "DM"  "PS"  "LAL" "CC"  "TR"  "BC"  "AH"  "WW"  "IP"  "CH" 
#[23] "CB"  "MB"  "DP"  "NYK" "P"   "OM"  "MH"  "BN"
```

Comment: Thank you @akrun, it was not exactly what I was going for but solves the problem anyway

Comment: I edited the question, I didn't fully explained my full needs, you still answered my prior question thus I upvoted your answer, but if you could include this into your answer I would be grateful

Comment: @DerekCorcoran  Based on the new update, do you have a custom replacement instead of the first 3 letters?  What about the `San Antonio Spurs`?

Comment: @DerekCorcoran  I updated the answer.  Please check if that is what you wanted

Answer (score 1):

### Initial response:

To answer your question using regular expression:

```
gsub("\\Â .*", "", teams)

## Store in object and print
teams2 <- gsub("\\Â .*", "", teams)
head(teams2)
## [1] "Golden State Warriors" "San Antonio Spurs"     "Houston Rockets"       "Los Angeles Clippers" 
## [5] "Utah Jazz"             "Oklahoma City Thunder"
```

You were on the right track, but instead of changing what you have, my strategy is to 1) find the common element (`Â`, the character followed by a space) and then 2) **drop** that common element.

Keep in mind you can run `gsub` multiple times, if necessary. For example:

```
teams <- gsub("\\Â .*", "", teams)
teams <- gsub("PATTERN2", "", teams)
teams <- gsub("PATTERN3", "", teams)
```

and so on.

### Update:

To return just the abbreviate form of strings, I pursued the "multiple `gsub`" approach that I suggested in the initial post, as follows:

```
teams <- gsub("\\Â .*", "", teams)
teams <- abbreviate(teams, named = F) #useful function to consider
teams <- gsub("[a-z]", "", teams)
## continue as needed
head(teams)
## [1] "GSW" "SAS" "HR"  "LAC" "UJ"  "OCT"
```

Comment: C, I edited the question, I didn't fully explained my full needs, you still answered my prior question thus I upvoted your answer, but if you could include this into your answer I would be grateful

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. I just worked it out by actually executing `gsub` multiple times as I had suggested. I'm about to update my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an idea that uses `stringi`

```
library(stringi) 
sapply(strsplit(stri_replace_last_regex(teams, '\\s+', ''), ' '), function(i)
                                            paste(substring(i, 1, 1), collapse = ''))
 #[1] "GSW" "SAS" "HR"  "LAC" "UJ"  "OCT" "MG"  "DN"  "PTB" "SK"  "NOP" "MT"  "DM"  "PS"  "LAL" "CC"  "TR"  "BC"  "AH"  "WW"  "IP"  "CH"  "CB" 
#[24] "MB"  "DP"  "NYK" "P7"  "OM"  "MH"  "BN"
```

or to get your desired output,

```
mapply(stri_replace_first_regex, teams, '\\w+', ind)
```